# Where to store state of a div?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for the best way to achieve this with jQuery: When I hover over a link, a div is displayed next to it. It's hidden again after I stop hovering. If I click the link, the div will remain until clicked again.

This seems like a natural solution to me, but I'm new to jQuery and would appreciate advice: Connect link.hover and link.click to logic that performs the above, storing the "has been clicked" boolean as a data attribute on the link.

Is that a good approach, or round-about?

Comment: Storing it as a data attribute is a good approach.

Comment: Would it make more sense to store it on the link or on the div?

Comment: I think on the link makes more sense.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I think you're looking for. Show/hide the `div` when you mouse over the `a` and keep the `div` visible when you click on the `a`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

    $("#thelink").on('mouseover', () => {
        // Change state if the link hasn't been clicked, otherwise do nothing
        if ($('#thelink').data("clicked") == false) {
            $("#thediv").show();
        }
    });

    $("#thelink").on('mouseout', () => {
        // Change state if the link hasn't been clicked, otherwise do nothing
        if ($('#thelink').data("clicked") == false) {
            $("#thediv").hide();
        }
    });

    $("#thelink").on('click', () => {
        $("#thelink").data("clicked", true);
        $("#thediv").show();
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="thelink" href="javascript:void(0)" data-clicked="false">The link</a>

<div hidden id="thediv">I am usually hidden. Mouse over the link to see me. Click on it and I'll stay visible.</div>
```

By the way, this is all easily done with vanilla js as well. I like showing people that jQuery isn't necessary for a lot of things these days, so here's the same thing with vanilla js:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    document.getElementById('thelink').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        const linkClicked = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('thelink').dataset['clicked']);
        if(linkClicked == false) {
            document.getElementById('thediv').hidden = false;
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('thelink').addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        const linkClicked = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('thelink').dataset['clicked']);
        if(linkClicked == false) {
            document.getElementById('thediv').hidden = true;
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('thelink').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('thelink').dataset['clicked'] = true;
        document.getElementById('thediv').hidden = false;
    });

})
```

```html
<a id="thelink" href="javascript:void(0)" data-clicked="false">The link</a>

<div hidden id="thediv">I am usually hidden. Mouse over the link to see me. Click on it and I'll stay visible.</div>
```

A bit more verbose, sure, but you're not depending on an external library. If `jQuery` makes your life easier, by all means use it, but please at least think about if you really need it.

Comment: Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Also programming is not about repeating code. Try to stick to DRY principles.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Why `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`? To your 2nd comment, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use **CSS** and the **Adjacent sibling combinator** `+`
Use **JavaScript** to handle the clicked state by using `Element.classList.toggle()`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.hov').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('is-hidden');
}));
```

```css
             .is-hidden { display: none;  }
.hov:hover + .is-hidden { display: block; }
```

```html
<a class="hov">HOVER / CLICK</a>
<div class="is-hidden">SOME CONTENT</div>
```

If you want to differentiate visually (improved UI) when that DIV is permanently visible - simply use another class:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.hov').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const El_next = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
  El_next.classList.toggle('is-hidden');
  El_next.classList.toggle('is-active');
}));
```

```css
             .is-hidden { display: none;  }
.hov:hover + .is-hidden { display: block; }
.is-active { background: #c0ffee; }
```

```html
<a class="hov">HOVER / CLICK</a>
<div class="is-hidden">SOME CONTENT</div>
```

If the element to toggle is distant (not a sibling) than an (anyways) preferred way to tackle the desired is to use `data-*` attribute to store the selector:

```js
const handleToggle = evt => {
  const EL_target = document.querySelector(evt.currentTarget.dataset.toggle);
  if (evt.type === 'click') {
    return EL_target.classList.toggle('is-active');
  }
  if (!EL_target.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    EL_target.classList.toggle('is-hidden');
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]').forEach(el => [
  'click',
  'mouseenter',
  'mouseleave',
].forEach(evtName => el.addEventListener(evtName, handleToggle)));
```

```css
.is-hidden { display: none; }
.is-active { background: #c0ffee; }
```

```html
<div class="something">
  <a class="hov" data-toggle="#el-1">HOVER / CLICK</a>
</div>

<div id="el-1" class="is-hidden">SOME CONTENT</div>
```